# Manipulating a data frame with contents from a different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large `data.frame` with geographic places names (`mydata`). The places appear in the `data.frame` in more than one cell.

In an other file with 3 columns I have all these places (first column), the latitude of these places (second the places appear in the `data.frame` in more than one cell). In an other file with 3 columns I have all these places (first column), the latitude of these places (second column) and the longitude in the third column.

I want to create two other matrices (`Lat` and `Long`) with dimension equal to 
the dimension of the `data.frame` with the geographic places such that:

```
Lat[i,j] = Latitude of the place in mydata[i,j]
long[i,j]= longitude of the place in mydata[i,j]
```

So I am looking for a procedure that go through `mydata`, pick the name of the place in each cell, look for the Latitude and Longitude in the second file and fill these values in the matrices `Lat` and `Long`.

```
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(c("xyz","ab","yabc",NA)), 
                           c("xyz","xyz","yabc","ab")),
                           c("ab","ab",NA,"yabc")))
Coor   <- data.frame(cbind(c("ab","xyz","yabc"), 
                           c(31.34,42.15,36.98), 
                           c(12.87,13.67,18.56)))
```

I want a method to get

```
Lat <- data.frame(cbind(c(42.15,31.34,36.98,NA),
                        c(42.15,42.15,36.98,31.34),
                        c(31.34,31.34,NA,36.98)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Lat<-do.call(cbind, lapply(mydata, function(curcol){ Coor[match(curcol, Coor[,1]), 2]  }))
```

That OK?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple procedure the produces what you want. There may be a way to do this without an explicit `for` loop using `*apply` and indices, but this is readable.

```
#Define columns explicitly, avoiding cbind and the resulting coercion to characters
mydata <- data.frame(X1=c("xyz","ab","yabc",NA),X2= c("xyz","xyz","yabc","ab"), X3=c("ab","ab",NA,"yabc"))
Coor   <- data.frame(X1=c("ab","xyz","yabc"),X2=c(31.34,42.15,36.98),X3=c(12.87,13.67,18.56))

Lat <- data.frame(cbind( c(42.15,31.34,36.98,NA),c(42.15,42.15,36.98,31.34),c(31.34,31.34,NA,36.98)))

#Create the new lat/long matrices to hold the result
Lat1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(mydata),ncol=ncol(mydata))
Long1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(mydata),ncol=ncol(mydata))

for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
    Lat1[,i] <- Coor[match(mydata[,i],Coor$X1),2]
    Long1[,i] <- Coor[match(mydata[,i],Coor$X1),3]
}
```

Comparing your desired output:

```
Lat
     X1    X2    X3
1 42.15 42.15 31.34
2 31.34 42.15 31.34
3 36.98 36.98    NA
4    NA 31.34 36.98

Lat1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 42.15 42.15 31.34
[2,] 31.34 42.15 31.34
[3,] 36.98 36.98    NA
[4,]    NA 31.34 36.98
```

And this is what this solution produces in `Long1`:

```
Long1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 13.67 13.67 12.87
[2,] 12.87 13.67 12.87
[3,] 18.56 18.56    NA
[4,]    NA 12.87 18.56
```