# R: Manipulating a data frame with contents from a different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: Manipulating a data frame with contents from a different data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152139/r-manipulating-a-data-frame-with-contents-from-a-different-data-frame)

I have a large dataframe with geographic places names (mydata). 
The places appear in the dataframe in more than one cell. 
In another file with 3 columns I have all these places (first column),
the latitude of these places (second column) and the longitude in the third column. 
I want to create two other matrices (Lat and Long) with dimension equal to 
the dimension of the dataframe with the geographic places such that:

- Lat[i,j] = Latitude of the place in mydata[i,j]
- long[i,j]= longitude of the place in mydata[i,j].

So I am looking for a procedure that go through mydata, pick the name of the place in each cell,
look for the Latitude en Longiude in the second file wand fill tese values in the matrices 
Lat and Long.
Herby an example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(c("xyz","ab","yabc",NA)),c("xyz","xyz","yabc","ab")),c("ab","ab",NA,"yabc")))
Coor   <- data.frame(cbind( c("ab","xyz","yabc"),c(31.34,42.15,36.98),c(12.87,13.67,18.56)))
```

The output should be:

```
Lat <- data.frame(cbind( c(42.15,31.34,36.98,NA),c(42.15,42.15,36.98,31.34),c(31.34,31.34,NA,36.98)))
```